# TSQL Split Function - Comma Delimited Parameter Values

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I've been trying to solve this issue where a sproc I'm using passes in user names with comma's in them. The part before the comma is a position prefix so for example, 'sel, MyName'. Our split function looks for commas to pass in something like this, 'sel, MyName, sel, YourName'.

I cannot figure out how to keep the comma but also separate the comma between names to perform the query against where username in (select result from dbo.split(@namestosplit)

I've tried removing the comma then putting it back, tried replacing temporarily, I've tried prefixing with the text (removing the prefix from the param's passed in)

Comment: It's hard to ascertain what you want without example data and desired results. Could you add those? And also what version of SQL-Server like 2012

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a way to do this.

```
select 'someprefix, ' + Item from Split(replace(@valueToSplit,'sel, ',''), ',')
```

This ends up forming a select like this: 
row 1: sel, Some Person
row 2: sel, Another Person

I essentially removed it to split the names then put it back as a concat for the where in (do something) piece.